# Sequelize Association in class methods not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to set associations in class methods but it's not working as it should!

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: (models) => {
            User.hasMany(models.AnotherModel, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
        },
   }
});
```

But when i set associations outside of `classMethods` block it works:

```
User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.AnotherModel, {foreignKey: 'userId'});
};
```

why the codes inside `classMethods` block not working?

*sequelize version: 4.2.0*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, the `classmethod` syntax refers to sequelize version < 4.

Since v4, sequelize has evolved more towards js class syntax and hence the change.

The upgrade manual [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html) details more about it

Comment: I used `sequelize-cli` to generate models and they should update to follow these changes.

Comment: Ideally, they should
I haven't tested the cli for sequelize > 4

Answer (score 1):

**with "sequelize": "5".**
Used this on my code to develop OSE server in Peru:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

const UserModel = sequelize.define('user', {
    user: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING
}, {});
UserModel.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
};
UserModel['getHashName'] = () => {
    return 'UserCache';
};
UserModel['getCacheKey'] = () => {
    return 'user';
};
UserModel['getCacheValue'] = () => {
    return 'password';
};
return UserModel;
};
```

and well, the next call :

```
console.log(User.getHashName());
console.log(User.getCacheKey());
console.log(User.getCacheValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember when library owners would leave the old method in place for a period of time, have it report that it's deprecated, but still operate so when we revisit a three year old project, and have zero idea why bringing the code forward breaks the entire universe, we might could get some direction on a resolution? I remember those days. Heady, wonderful days, those.

We're in the middle of a large code-forward update, bringing an old application to the modern versions of Node, et al, and holy crap, everything is just flat out broken. This'll be fun.

Digging in, this is "expected behavior", but wow, what a horrible way to learn about it. :(