# How create a association between tables (composite key) using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

sup guys! I'm creating an app tinder like, now I'm building the match system. The tool is sequelize to manage the database, atm I'm facing a issue when I try to get the user (from `users` table) together with a field called `proposerUserUsedSuperLike` in another table called: `userMatch`. This is `userMatch`'s structure:

`proposerUserId` (int pk)
`accepterUserId` (int pk)
`bothAccepted` (int)
`proposerUserUsedSuperLike` (int)

So the target here it's to bring a randon user from `users` (already done) TOGETHER with the field `proposerUserUsedSuperLike` from `userMacth` table (not done yet).

To make it more clear, when I send a request to the api to select a profile to show to currently user, I want to select the profile AND I need to know if that profile already used it's super like on the currently user, if so, I'll show a sign in their picture.

EDIT: Also, every time that a user click on Like Button, or Super Like Button, it will generate (or update if already exists) a record on `userMacth`'s table using both user IDs.

This is the currently migration that I'm using:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('userMatch', {
      proposerUserId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      },
      accepterUserId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      },
      proposerUserUsedSuperLike: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
      },
      bothAccepted: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
      },
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('userMatch');
  }
};
```

And this is my `UserMatch` model:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

class UserMatch extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            proposerUserId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            accepterUserId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            bothAccepted: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            proposerUserUsedSuperLike: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }, {
            classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                    UserMatch.belongsToMany(models.User, { foreignKey: 'id' })
                }
            },
            sequelize,//conexão
            tableName: 'userMatch',
            underscored: false
        })
    }
}

module.exports = UserMatch;
```

And this is the error that I'm getting: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: UserMatch is not associated to User!`

EDIT²: Some more info about model connection:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const dbConfig = require('../config/dbConfig')
const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig)

const User = require('../models/User')
const Contact = require('../models/Contact')
const UserImage = require('../models/UserImage')
const UserMatch = require('../models/UserMatch')

User.init(connection)
Contact.init(connection)
UserImage.init(connection)
UserMatch.init(connection)

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: Where do you call `associate` method of the registered `UserMatch` model?

Comment: right after you register your model classes in Sequelize

Comment: my mistake, actually I call it, as you can see in this line here: `associate: function (models) {` But I don't really know if this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: At this line you just declare this function. Ok, add a code where you create an instance of Sequelize and register models

Comment: I updated main post with a edit² at the final adding some new info about model connection.

Comment: It seems that you define models in Sequelize v3 style but actually using Sequelize v4. Am I right?

Comment: oh actually I have not much experience using sequelize, can you post an example of how it should be done using sequelize v4? Thanks man!

EDIT²: I saw here in my package.json and confirmed that I'm using v5 of sequelize ^5.21.5

Comment: Look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889345/sequelize-association-in-class-methods-not-working